# Facebook Log in failure using easyfacebook library android?

Tags: android, facebook-login

When i am login into facebook using easyfacebook library whenever app goes online , then if i am downloading and running the app it fails to log in to facebook in android new versions.
it working fine with android old versions.
I am not able to understand the actual problem.
Please help.

Comment: How can we help without seeing your code or error message???

Comment: gonna guess the OP is doing network code on the UI thread

Comment: I guys thanks for comments got solved the issue.